# Getting top 1 in single table with CTE of Prev Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
;WITH  CTE
          AS ( SELECT   rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY sd.slogid desc) ,
                        sd.slogid ,
                        sd.sid ,
                        sd.statusid
               FROM     statusdetails sd
             )
    SELECT TOP ( 1 )
            cte.slogid,
            CTE.statusid,
            cte.sid ,
            nex.stausid NextValue
    FROM    CTE
            LEFT JOIN CTE prev ON prev.rownum = CTE.rownum - 1
            LEFT JOIN CTE nex ON nex.rownum = CTE.rownum + 1
    WHERE   CTE.statusid <> nex.statusid
```

I am having `n` numbers of `sid` and want to get for each group `top 1`.

Sample data :

```
 Slogid        Sid      Statusid

186877          98929         105

186826          98929         105

186821          98929         104
```

I want to get the `slogid` - 186826, when there is a status change prev id I want to get it from each group of `Sid`.

Comment: What are you wanting to group by? Look at the partition by clause of ROW_NUMBER(), and then partition by that.

Comment: Yes,
Slogid  Sid     Statusid
186877 98929 105
186826 98929 105
186821 98929 104
This is the table, I want to get the Slogid - 186826, when the change happen in statusid, I want to get the prev id from the table. Is it clear.

Comment: @user3619447 You cannot format properly in comments, please edit your question and add your sample data and expected output to the question. Thanks.

Comment: I think you want the latest statusID, right? Also let me know what will be the next statusID for Sid 98929?

Comment: I need latest Slogid once the status is changed from the above example(186826)

Answer (score 2):

```
;WITH  CTE AS 
( SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sid ORDER BY sd.slogid desc) RN,
                        sd.slogid ,
                        sd.sid ,
                        sd.statusid
               FROM     statusdetails sd
             )
    SELECT TOP ( 1 )
            cte.slogid,
            CTE.statusid,
            cte.sid ,
            nex.stausid NextValue
    FROM    CTE
            LEFT JOIN CTE prev ON prev.rownum = CTE.rownum - 1
            LEFT JOIN CTE nex ON nex.rownum = CTE.rownum + 1
    WHERE   CTE.statusid <> nex.statusid
    AND RN = 1;
```

Comment: The change will not be at the first itself it may be in 'n' row

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to partition your row_number function by `sid` to ensure status changes are linked to the same `sid`:

```
rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `sid` ORDER BY sd.slogid desc) ,
```

Assuming this is what you want then you are missing a JOIN condition here:

```
FROM    CTE
        LEFT JOIN CTE prev ON prev.rownum = CTE.rownum - 1
        LEFT JOIN CTE nex ON nex.rownum = CTE.rownum + 1
```

You also need to join on `sid` otherwise you will get a cross join, so your join should be:

```
FROM    CTE
        LEFT JOIN CTE prev ON prev.sid = CTE.sid AND prev.rownum = CTE.rownum - 1
        LEFT JOIN CTE nex ON nex.sid = CTE.sid AND nex.rownum = CTE.rownum + 1
```

I am not sure why you join to previous though as you never actually use this in the select. I personally would be more inclined to use [APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to get the previous status:

```
SELECT  sd.slogid ,
        sd.sid,
        sd.statusid,
        NextValue = n.statusid
FROM    statusdetails AS sd
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 n.statusid
            FROM    statusdetails AS n
            WHERE   n.sid = sd.sid
            AND     n.slogid > sd.slogid
            ORDER BY n.slogid
        ) n
WHERE   sd.statusid != n.statusid;
```

Finally, I am not sure if you want the the top 1 record per sid, or just the top one. In your query you have used `TOP` without an order by clause which is not deterministic, so shouldn't be done. If you want the top 1 per sid though you need to use `ROW_NUMBER` to get this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  sd.slogid ,
            sd.sid,
            sd.statusid,
            NextValue = n.statusid,
            RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY sd.sid ORDER BY sd.slogid DESC)
    FROM    statusdetails AS sd
            CROSS APPLY
            (   SELECT  TOP 1 n.statusid
                FROM    statusdetails AS n
                WHERE   n.sid = sd.sid
                AND     n.slogid > sd.slogid
                ORDER BY n.slogid
            ) n
    WHERE   sd.statusid != n.statusid
)
SELECT  slogid, sid, statusid, NextValue
FROM    CTE
WHERE   RowNum = 1;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e02c0/5)**

For the sake of completeness, this is your query (using ROW_NUMBER to get the next status) with the corrections made:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(   SELECT  rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sd.sid ORDER BY sd.slogid desc) ,
            sd.slogid ,
            sd.sid ,
            sd.statusid
    FROM    statusdetails sd
), CTE2 AS
(   SELECT  cte.slogid,
            CTE.statusid,
            cte.sid ,
            NextValue = nex.statusid,
            RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cte.sid ORDER BY cte.slogid DESC)
    FROM    CTE
            LEFT JOIN CTE nex 
                ON nex.sid = CTE.sid
                AND nex.rownum = CTE.rownum + 1
    WHERE   CTE.statusid <> nex.statusid
)
SELECT  slogid, statusid, sid, NextValue
FROM    CTE2
WHERE   RowNum = 1;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e02c0/7)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;WITH  CTE AS 
(SELECT   
    rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY sd.slogid desc) ,
    grouprownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY sd.[sid] ORDER BY sd.slogid desc) 
    sd.slogid ,
    sd.sid ,
    sd.statusid
 FROM     
    statusdetails sd          
)
    SELECT 
            cte.slogid,
            CTE.statusid,
            cte.sid ,
            nex.stausid NextValue
    FROM    CTE
            LEFT JOIN CTE prev ON prev.rownum = CTE.rownum - 1
            LEFT JOIN CTE nex ON nex.rownum = CTE.rownum + 1
    WHERE   CTE.statusid <> nex.statusid
            AND CTE.grouprownum=1
```

Comment: It is working fine when there is a change in next row itself. But it is failing when 
stausid 
id
101
101
102

Comment: are you sure about the joins and where conditions . Does that makes trouble for status id 101 101 102??

Comment: yes, 
Slogid Sid Statusid 
186877 98929 105         
186826 98929 105      
186821 98929 104   
This is the table, I want to get the Slogid - 186826, when the change happen in statusid, I want to get the prev id from the table. Is it clear.

Comment: Slogid          Sid   Statusid
186877       98929 105
186826       98929 105
186821      98929 104